# quantum work distribution from sudden quench

Tags: quantum-mechanics, work, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to calculate the quantum work distribution P(W) from a sudden quench, which the expression is

$P(W) = \sum_{n,m}p_n^0p_{m|n}^\tau \delta[W - (\epsilon_m^\tau - \epsilon_n^0)],$

where $p_n^0$ and $p_{m|n}^\tau$ I can obtain from the eigenvectors of $H_0$ and $H_\tau$ Hamiltonians, respectively, and $\epsilon_n^0$ and $\epsilon_m^\tau$ are the eigenvalues.

My question is: how do I obtain $W$? And what do I evaluate the $\delta$ in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The work distribution measures the probability of the doing a certain amount of work on the system as it evolves, normally interacting with some sort of envirnoment. Here $W$ is the amount of work done on the system, so it is an external parameter you plug into the distribution.

The delta function is pulling out pairs of eigenstates with an energy difference of exactly $W$. Exactly how you deal with this will depend on whether (or which parts of) the spectrums of $H_0$ and $H_\tau$ are continuous or discrete. If at least 1 is contiuous then you can turn the sums over eigenstates into integrals and use this to evaluate the delta function. If both are discrete then you are going to end up with a 'spikey' distribution, with raw delta functions in it, which is not a problem but is more messy to deal with. It may be simpler in this case to deal with a different but realted objec, such as the cumulative distribution.